tesseract not able to find .lstm-unicharset file while performing model training
I am using tesseract to perfrom custom model training. I have created my own text dataset and saved in tesstrain->data->codec folder with images and corresponding .gt files. At the same level as tesstrain folder I have langdata folder and tessdata_best folder.Also I have tesseract directory whic I have cloned from the official site and inside that I have tessdata folder which has eng.traineddata file. I'm running this command to start training:
TESSDATA_PREFIX=../tesseract/tessdata make training MODEL_NAME=codec START_MODEL=eng TESSDATA=../tesseract/tessdata MAX_ITERATIONS=1000

I am getting this error after running the command. I think is is not able to create .lstm-unicharset file.
